# Deriving joint and marginal distributions, from exponential conditional distribution.

Tags: statistics

Let $X$ be continuously distributed with density $f(x) = x$ on [0, $\sqrt{2}$], and let $Y|X$ be exponential with parameter $X$ (i.e. $f(y|x) = x^{-1}e^{-y/x}$). Derive $f(x,y)$. Derive $f(y)$ from $f(x,y)$. Then prove $f(y) = E[f(y|X)]$.

I feel kind of a dumb, but am stuck on this problem. I feel it should be quite easy, but the integration is not coming. My work thus far:

$f(x)f(y|x)=f(y,x) \Rightarrow \dfrac{x}{xe^{y/x}} = f(y,x) \Rightarrow f(y,x) =e ^{-y/x}$

$f(y) = \int_0^{\sqrt{2}} e^{-y/x}\,dx $

When I try U-substitution, it doesn't work, and I can think of no other way to integrate this.  This leads me to believe my $f(y,x)$ may by incorrect.

I apologize if this is a rudimentary question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that your lecture has exponential with 1/x and not with x? I mean that $f(y|x)=xe^{-xy}$ is possible, since that form of the exponential is also used in many books

Comment: That is a bit confusing. He tells us its exponential with parameter X, then gives us the exponential with parameter 1/X. I just could be reading it wrong. Thanks

Comment: Then it is as he says (as you have it). Ok, your welcome.